# How to delete a row in cassandra materialiezed view?

Tags: cassandra, materialized-views

I have a cassadra namespace with a table and a materialized view from it. 
A row got deleted in the base table but the change was not propagated to the materialized view. I don't know the exact reason why this happend.

So now I am stuck with that row in the MV and I am not able to delete it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, materialized views are still very much broken.  The two main problems are:

1. There isn't a way to know when a MV is out of sync.
2. Once it's out of sync, there really isn't a way to get it back in sync.

So it sounds like you're past point #1.

There *is* a `nodetool rebuild_view` command, but it does not clear-out existing data, which is what you would need.

Unfortunately, I think the only path forward is to `DROP` the view and re-create it.